# Save clicked image in a var and set it as background for a then shown new div - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, this is my code, it's for a school project - I'm totally new to jQuery, learning it kinda all by myself, so I hope I didn't mess up too much.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var img_amount = $(".lboximg").length;
$(".lboxmid").hide();
$(".lboxgrey").hide();

$(".lboximg").click(function(){
    //alert(img_amount);
    var lboxmid_bg = $(this).find(".lboximg");
    $(".lboxmid").css({
        "background-image" : lboxmid_bg
    });
    $(".lboxmid").show();
    $(".lboxgrey").show();
});
$(".lboxgrey").click(function(){
    $(".lboxmid").hide();
    $(".lboxgrey").hide();
});
```

});

The plan is that on click the clicked image will be saved in the var lboxmid_bg, which then will become the background-image of the div with the class lboxmid which gets shown on click aswell. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Also, the var img_amount is leftover from my original plan which I early scrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".lboximg").click(function(){
    var lboxmid_bg = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".lboxmid").css({
        "background-image" : 'url('+ lboxmid_bg +')'
    });
    $(".lboxmid").show();
    $(".lboxgrey").show();
});
```